# How to make a child centered on both axis with the other childs surrounding it?

Tags: html, css

[image]Let's see an example:

```css
.wrapper{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  overflow-y: hidden
}
.you{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 300%
}
.others{
  margin: 0 10px
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1 class="you">you</h1>
    <p class="others">others</p>
    <p class="others">others</p>
    <p class="others">others</p>
    <p class="others">others</p>
    <p class="others">others</p>
    <p class="others">others</p>
    <p class="others">others</p>
    <p class="others">others</p>
    <p class="others">others</p>
    <p class="others">others</p>
    <p class="others">others</p>
    <p class="others">others</p>
    <p class="others">others</p>
    <p class="others">others</p>
    <p class="others">others</p>
    <p class="others">others</p>
    <p class="others">others</p>
    <p class="others">others</p>
    <p class="others">others</p>
    <p class="others">others</p>
    <p class="others">others</p>
    <p class="others">others</p>
    <p class="others">others</p>
    <p class="others">others</p>
    <p class="others">others</p>
    <p class="others">others</p>
    <p class="others">others</p>
    <p class="others">others</p>
    <p class="others">others</p>
    <p class="others">others</p>
    <p class="others">others</p>
    <p class="others">others</p>
    <p class="others">others</p>
    <p class="others">others</p>
    <p class="others">others</p>
    <p class="others">others</p>
    <p class="others">others</p>
    <p class="others">others</p>
    <p class="others">others</p>
    <p class="others">others</p>
    <p class="others">others</p>
    <p class="others">others</p>
    <p class="others">others</p>
    <p class="others">others</p>
    <p class="others">others</p>
    <p class="others">others</p>
    <p class="others">others</p>
    <p class="others">others</p>
    <p class="others">others</p>
    <p class="others">others</p>
</div>
```

I want to perfectly center the you in the way that it doesn't overlap the others. I always use flexbox, but it looks like that it will not be the solution. I'm thinking about grid, and to calculate the rows and columns manually, but there must be an elegant way to do this. Please let me know if it is.

Comment: if it is possible, could you share a screenshot of the desired final results?

Comment: No, not possible without knowing row heights / element widths.

Comment: you can do it with grid, each 'others' word can be in a column, and the 'you' can be an  merged area.

Answer (score 0):

Using `display:grid`, you can achieve the effect that you are looking for:

```
<style>
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(8,1fr) ;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}
.others {

  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
}
.you{
    font-size: 82px;
    grid-area: 4 / 3 / 6 / 7;
     text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>



<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="you">you</div>
  <div class="others">others</div>
  <div class="others">others</div>
  <div class="others">others</div>  
  <div class="others">others</div>
  <div class="others">others</div>
  <div class="others">others</div>  
  <div class="others">others</div>
  <div class="others">others</div>
  <div class="others">others</div>
  <div class="others">others</div>
  <div class="others">others</div>
  <div class="others">others</div>  
  <div class="others">others</div>
  <div class="others">others</div>
  <div class="others">others</div>  
  <div class="others">others</div>
  <div class="others">others</div>
  <div class="others">others</div>  
  <div class="others">others</div>
  <div class="others">others</div>
  <div class="others">others</div>  
  <div class="others">others</div>
  <div class="others">others</div>
  <div class="others">others</div>  
  <div class="others">others</div>
  <div class="others">others</div>
  <div class="others">others</div>
  <div class="others">others</div>
  <div class="others">others</div>
  <div class="others">others</div>  
  <div class="others">others</div>
  <div class="others">others</div>
  <div class="others">others</div>  
  <div class="others">others</div>
  <div class="others">others</div>
  <div class="others">others</div>
  <div class="others">others</div>
  <div class="others">others</div>
  <div class="others">others</div>  
  <div class="others">others</div>
  <div class="others">others</div>
  <div class="others">others</div>  
  <div class="others">others</div>
  <div class="others">others</div>
  <div class="others">others</div>
  <div class="others">others</div>
  <div class="others">others</div>
  <div class="others">others</div>
   <div class="others">others</div>
  <div class="others">others</div>  
  <div class="others">others</div>
  <div class="others">others</div>
  <div class="others">others</div>
  <div class="others">others</div>
  <div class="others">others</div>
  <div class="others">others</div>
</div>

</body>
```

grid-area: 4 / 3 / 6 / 7; this line makes the word 'others' wrap around the 'you' word, how? by using the space in columns and rows that if the word 'others' were there.